# T-SQL get SELECTed value of stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, select

In T-SQL, this is allowed:

```
DECLARE @SelectedValue int
SELECT @SelectedValue = MyIntField FROM MyTable WHERE MyPrimaryKeyField = 1
```

So, it's possible to get the value of a SELECT and stuff it in a variable (provided it's scalar, obviously).

If I put the same select logic in a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyInt
AS
SELECT MyIntField FROM MyTable WHERE MyPrimaryKeyField = 1
```

Can I get the output of this stored procedure and stuff it in a variable?

Something like:

```
DECLARE @SelectedValue int
SELECT @SelectedValue = EXEC GetMyInt
```

(I know the syntax above is not allowed because I tried it!)

Answer (score 199, accepted):

there are three ways you can use: the RETURN value, and OUTPUT parameter and a result set

ALSO, watch out if you use the pattern:  `SELECT @Variable=column FROM table ...`

if there are multiple rows returned from the query, your @Variable will only contain the value from the last row returned by the query.

**RETURN VALUE**
since your query returns an int field, at least based on how you named it.  you can use this trick:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyInt
( @Param int)
AS
DECLARE @ReturnValue int

SELECT @ReturnValue=MyIntField FROM MyTable WHERE MyPrimaryKeyField = @Param
RETURN @ReturnValue
GO
```

and now call your procedure like:

```
DECLARE @SelectedValue int
       ,@Param         int
SET @Param=1
EXEC @SelectedValue = GetMyInt @Param
PRINT @SelectedValue
```

this will only work for INTs, because RETURN can only return a single int value and nulls are converted to a zero.

**OUTPUT PARAMETER**
you can use an output parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyInt
( @Param     int
 ,@OutValue  int OUTPUT)
AS
SELECT @OutValue=MyIntField FROM MyTable WHERE MyPrimaryKeyField = @Param
RETURN 0
GO
```

and now call your procedure like:

```
DECLARE @SelectedValue int
       ,@Param         int
SET @Param=1
EXEC GetMyInt @Param, @SelectedValue OUTPUT
PRINT @SelectedValue
```

Output parameters can only return one value, but can be any data type

**RESULT SET**
for a result set make the procedure like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyInt
( @Param     int)
AS
SELECT MyIntField FROM MyTable WHERE MyPrimaryKeyField = @Param
RETURN 0
GO
```

use it like:

```
DECLARE @ResultSet table (SelectedValue int)
DECLARE @Param int
SET @Param=1
INSERT INTO @ResultSet (SelectedValue)
    EXEC GetMyInt @Param
SELECT * FROM @ResultSet
```

result sets can have many rows and many columns of any data type

Comment: Note the result set approach requires this table/insert usage, even if only one record is returned. I was looking for a shortcut directly into a variable, but there isn't one.

Comment: is it possible to use the 'return value' and  'output parameter' approach in multiple row result?

Comment: @ji-ruh,a stored procedure can use one, none, some, or all: result set, return output parameters, and/or return value

Answer (score 4):

There is also a combination, you can use a return value with a recordset:

--Stored Procedure--

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [TestProc]

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Temp TABLE
    (
        [Name] VARCHAR(50)
    )

    INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('Mark') 
    INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('John') 
    INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('Jane') 
    INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('Mary') 

    -- Get recordset
    SELECT * FROM @Temp

    DECLARE @ReturnValue INT
    SELECT @ReturnValue = COUNT([Name]) FROM @Temp

    -- Return count
    RETURN @ReturnValue

END
```

--Calling Code--

```
DECLARE @SelectedValue int
EXEC @SelectedValue = [TestProc] 

SELECT @SelectedValue
```

--Results--

[image]

Comment: How do I get this results in php?

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to use return values.

```
DECLARE @SelectedValue int

CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyInt (@MyIntField int OUTPUT)
AS
SELECT @MyIntField = MyIntField FROM MyTable WHERE MyPrimaryKeyField = 1
```

Then you call it like this:

```
EXEC GetMyInt OUTPUT @SelectedValue
```

Answer (score 2):

Try do this:

```
EXEC @SelectedValue = GetMyInt
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  A SELECT statement does not become the SPROC's return value unless specified inside the SPROC.