# Execute a result in  SQL Server using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I need to execute result (already in form of SQL) itself of an SQL query to get the final result.

So, it should be like, in first query I execute

```
Select Top(1) RequiredQuery as ReqQry from EPMaster
```

I'll get another query in result in `ReqQry` that will then be executed in form another query to get the final result.

The second query will also require some parameters to be passed at where clause, like when I do:

```
Select Top(1) RequiredQuery as ReqQry 
from EPMaster 
--ReqQry after its execution returns:
Select Top(1) (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as FullName 
from DPMaster 
where DmID = @DomainID and PnID = @PersonID
```

I'll be passing the Params `@DomainID` and `@PersonID` from my C# project's DAL layer.

So I guess it should be done with the help of a stored procedure.

-----------------More Explanation-------------

Here, one SQL statement is executed to get the next SQL statement which will be the resultant of the former statement. When you execute 1st query, you get 2nd query in result, which you execute again to get the final result

The second query needs 2 parameters to execute that are `@DomainID` and `@PersonID` which will be passed by me from my C# Project. So, if I make a stored procedure for handeling all this and pass the required parameters, along with the 1'st query from my project, it should first execute 1st query then execute 2nd query (with parameters `PersonID` and `DomainID`) that was received as result of 1st query, after which I get the final result.

Comment: I don't understand your needs properly. But may you would like to use dynamic SQL in your stored porcedure?

Comment: Here, 1 SQL statement is executed to get the next SQL statement which will be the resultant of the former statement. When you execute 1st query, you get 2nd query in result, which you execute again to get the final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **Dynamic SQL**, to get running the returned nvarchar(max) query string from the first procedure / query.

**Edit:**

```
DECLARE @ResultOfTheFirstQuery nvarchar(max)

SELECT @ResultOfTheFirstQuery = (Select Top(1)RequiredQuery 
                                 as ReqQry from EPMaster)

exec sp_executeSql @ResultOfTheFirstQuery
```

Or if you need a complex logic, you can write an other SP, which can heve a return value:

```
DECLARE @ResultOfTheFirstQuery nvarchar(max)

SELECT @ResultOfTheFirstQuery = FirstStoredprocedure @params

exec sp_executeSql @ResultOfTheFirstQuery
```

Here is an already [well answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881024/t-sql-get-selected-value-of-stored-procedure) how to get the paramater return. You can use `RETURN` or `OUTPUT` parameter.

Here is how to use the [sp_executeSql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @SQL as nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = (Select Top(1)RequiredQuery as ReqQry from EPMaster);
EXEC (@SQL);
```

Comment: _Incorrect syntax near '@SQL'_ is what I am getting as result

Comment: Try using `EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL` instead

Comment: the error is that you're missing "set" when you assign into @sql

Comment: Indeed it is. I was doing it off the top of my head.