# How to capture JSON data from a stored procedure for testing with tSQLt

Tags: json, sql-server-2016, tsqlt

I'm trying to use tSQLt to test a stored procedure that returns JSON data. The database is running under SQL Server 2016. The stored procedure is as follows (simplified considerably):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SearchForThings]
    @SearchText NVARCHAR(1000),
    @MaximumRowsToReturn INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(@MaximumRowsToReturn)
        [Id],
        [ItemName]
    FROM
        [BigTableOfThings] AS bt
    WHERE 
        bt.[Tags] LIKE N'%' + @SearchText + N'%'
    ORDER BY 
        bt.[ItemName]
    FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT(N'Things');
END;
```

This can't be tested in the same way XML can - I've tried a test table, as below, which was suggested [in this related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271112/tsqlt-returning-results-from-a-stored-procedure) -

```
CREATE TABLE #JsonResult (JsonData NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT #JsonResult (JsonData) 
    EXEC [SearchForThings] 'cats',10
```

The above code produces this error:

> The FOR JSON clause is not allowed in a INSERT statement.

I cannot alter the stored procedure under test. How can I capture the JSON result?

Comment: Can you not execute the `select statement` in  SQL Server Management Studio and view the result?

Comment: @CliveSeebregts Can you clarify how that would help with testing this stored procedure in a tSQLt unit test?

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought you were looking for a sample output of the query

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to modify the stored proc, your last ditch effort would be to use `OPENROWSET`. Here's how you would call it in your case:

```
INSERT INTO #JsonResult
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=[ServerNameGoesHere];Trusted_Connection=yes;','EXEC SearchForThings ''cats'',10')
```

If you get an error, you can use the following to enable ad hoc distributed queries:

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: Uggh. I was afraid of OPENROWSET being the only option.  Trying to do this with a least-privilege account is challenging (to say the least) from a security perspective.  Hopefully a future version of SQL will make working with JSON output a bit less painful.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is two years on but I stumbled on this today when trying to solve a different tSQLt problem.

Your issue occurs because the column being returned from your stored procedure is not explicity named. If you provide a column name for the JSON data you can insert the data into a #temp table, e.g.:

```sql
create table BigTableOfThings (
    Id int not null,
    ItemName nvarchar(50) not null,
    Tags nvarchar(50) not null
);
insert BigTableOfThings values
    (1, 'Whiskers', 'Cool for Cats'),
    (2, 'Barkley', 'Dogs Rule!');
GO
create procedure SearchForThings
    @SearchText nvarchar(1000),
    @MaximumRowsToReturn int
as
begin
    select [JsonData] = (
        select top(@MaximumRowsToReturn)
            Id,
            ItemName
        from
            BigTableOfThings as bt
        where 
            bt.Tags like N'%' + @SearchText + N'%'
        order by
            bt.ItemName
        for json auto, root(N'Things')
    );
end
go
create table #JsonResult (JsonData nvarchar(max));
insert #JsonResult (JsonData) 
    exec SearchForThings 'cats',10;
select * from #JsonResult;
go
```

Which yields...

```
{"Things":[{"Id":1,"ItemName":"Whiskers"}]}
```