# Cannot get rid of the "procedure attempted to return a status of NULL" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view, null

I'm trying to get a value from a stored procedure.

```
USE FoodDB
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('spCalCount') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROC spCalCount
GO

CREATE PROC spCalCount
    @FoodGroup varchar(25) = '%',
    @Name varchar(25) = '%'
AS

DECLARE @NumCalories decimal(4,1) 

SET @NumCalories = (SELECT SUM(MealCalories)
                    FROM CalsPerMeal
                    WHERE FoodGroup LIKE @FoodGroup 
                    AND Name LIKE @Name)

RETURN @NumCalories
```

CalsPerMeal is a view that combines a few tables. This is the only thing that I can think of that is causing the error.

```
USE FoodDB

DECLARE @Count decimal(4,1)
EXEC @Count = spCalCount 'Fruit', 'Jason'
PRINT 'Jason has eaten ' + CONVERT(varchar,@Count,1) + ' Fruit Calories'
```

And the error I keep getting is this:

```
The 'spCalCount' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is
not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.
Jason has eaten 0.0 Fruit Calories
```

I also tried this variation with an output parameter, and still got NULL

```
USE FoodDB
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('spCalCount') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROC spCalCount
GO

CREATE PROC spCalCount
    @NumCalories decimal(4,1) OUTPUT,
    @FoodGroup varchar(25) = '%',
    @Name varchar(50) = '%'
AS
SELECT @NumCalories = (SELECT SUM(MealCalories)
                FROM CalsPerMeal
                WHERE FoodGroup LIKE @FoodGroup 
                AND Name LIKE @Name)
```

And the execution:

```
USE FoodDB

DECLARE @Count decimal(4,1)
EXEC spCalCount @Count OUTPUT, 'Fruit', 'Jason'
SELECT @Count AS JasonFruitCals
```

This doesn't give me the error, but it still returns NULL

Comment: FYI, your `FoodGroup LIKE @FoodGroup` and `Name LIKE @Name` are very inefficient ways to make the parameters optional, and will run slow when you have lots of data.

Comment: is this for SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, it is SQL Server

Comment: So nothing matches the `where` clause.  That seems simple to understand.

Comment: You're right, Gordon. I needed a wildcard character for the @Name parameter.
Ugh. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks like SQL Server, as such a `RETURN` value must be a non-NULL INT.  It is warning you that it is changing the NULL to zero.

your query:

```
SET @NumCalories = (SELECT SUM(MealCalories)
                    FROM CalsPerMeal
                    WHERE FoodGroup LIKE @FoodGroup 
                    AND Name LIKE @Name)
```

must result in @NumCalories bring NULL, thus no rows to SUM(), so SQL Server is converting your NULL return to zero.

It is best to only return an execution status value via `RETURN`, like 0=good, -1=warning, 1=fatal error, etc.  If you need to pass back a single value, like you are doing here, use an OUTPUT parameter.  You can only `RETURN` an int, so if you want decimals, you need to use an output parameter.  Output parameters can be of any type, so it would be a good choice for your decimal value.

see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2881863/65223

Comment: I tried another variation with an output parameter. I edited my post to show it. It still didn't work.

Comment: your query finds no rows, run this, what comes back? `SELECT * FROM CalsPerMeal WHERE FoodGroup LIKE 'Fruit' AND Name LIKE  'Jason'`  you only add the wild card if the parameter is not passed in. are you trying to run this: `SELECT * FROM CalsPerMeal WHERE FoodGroup LIKE '%Fruit%' AND Name LIKE  '%Jason%'` or something else???

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the RETURN in ISNULL

```
RETURN ISNULL(@NumCalories,0)
```

SQL Server is expecting an integer and NULL is not an integer value.