# What is the correct way to capture OUTPUT deleted.x from EXEC stored_procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using a table as a [FIFO queue](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) under high concurrency conditions, and dequeueing atomically like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [jobs].[DequeueJob]        
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP(1) 
    FROM jobs.JobQueue WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST) 
    OUTPUT deleted.JobID;
END
```

I call this stored procedure from another to capture and use the `deleted.JobID`, so I have this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [jobs].[GetJob]        
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Job TABLE (JobID int)       

    INSERT @Job EXEC jobs.DequeueJob    

    DECLARE @JobID int
    SET @JobID = (SELECT JobID from @Job)   

    UPDATE jobs.Jobs 
    SET IsInQueue = 0 
    WHERE JobID = @JobID

    SELECT * 
    FROM jobs.Jobs 
    WHERE JobID = @JobID
END
```

This works fine, but it smells: to get the value (`JobID`) that I want to use, I have to create a table variable with one column, `INSERT` a row into it, and then immediately `SELECT` that same row back out. Is there a better way (from either a readability or optimization perspective) to capture `deleted.JobID` when I call `EXEC jobs.DequeueJob` that will not break its atomicity?

`EXEC @JobID = jobs.DequeueJob` is valid syntax and looked promising, but it captures the return value, not the `OUTPUT` value. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2881863/2394348) has a good discussion of several result-passing options, but I can't find a way to fit my situation to any of them.

I'm using SQL Server 2012 SP3, but I'm prepared to upgrade if improved syntax for this is available in a newer version.

Comment: In my thoughts there is no better way than output deleted.id into @tablevariable

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Shakeer Mirza's comment that inserting the OUTPUT clause result into a table is unavoidable since that's the only way the value can be used in T-SQL. Unless, you have a specific reason for separate procs, you could refactor like the example below, which is slightly less smelly, IMHO.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [jobs].[GetNextJob]        
AS

DECLARE @Job TABLE ( JobID int PRIMARY KEY );

DELETE TOP(1) FROM jobs.JobQueue WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
OUTPUT deleted.JobID INTO @Job(JobID);

UPDATE jobs.Jobs set IsInQueue = 0 
OUTPUT inserted.*
WHERE JobID = (SELECT JobID from @Job);
GO
```

Note that there is no defined order with `DELETE TOP` so, if you require FIFO, consider using a subquery with `ORDER BY` in the `DELETE`.