# Run a procedure and throw its data as a parameter in an insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Is it possible to execute a procedure to save the values ​​that it generates to assign as a parameter to make an `INSERT` in an excel worksheet?

Example: The procedure returns me this data:

[image]

Then I wanted to get this data I brought and make an `INSERT` in an excel spreadsheet. If so, what would be the rationale for this procedure?

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP.NET?  You're talking about Excel but you use terminology from SQL (procedure, parameter, insert). Please rephrase your question to be clearer about what tools and systems you're using.

Comment: @Dai 
Yes, because I have to implement this process in an ASP.NET application I'm working on.
I know I can read an .XLS file, but I would like to know if I can do an INSERT with generated data from a procedure

Comment: Can you make insert from procedure ? YES you CAN. But I bealive it's better to do this in other SQL procedure that you will call in your .NET Application.

How to  get date from procedures you will find here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881024/t-sql-get-selected-value-of-stored-procedure